# Binding command line arguments to the object methods calls in Python

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I am working on a command line utility with a few possible arguments. The argument parsing is done with argparse module. In the end, with some additional customization, I get a dictionary with one and only one element:

```
{'add_account': ['example.com', 'example']}
```

Where the key is an option that should translate to a method call and the value is the arguments list.
I have all the planned objects method implemented.
I wonder what would be the best, most pythonic way to create method calls based on received dictionary.
I could obviously go through a predefined mapping like:

```
if option == 'add_account':
    object.add_account(
                       dictionary['add_account'][0],
                       dictionary['add_account'][1]
                       )
```

I feel that there's a much better way to do it, though.

Comment: make `add_account` accept lists, and just pass `dictionary['add_account']`

Comment: Or let it remain, and use `*dictionary['add_account']`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getattr` to fetch a method object (`argparse.py` uses this approach several times).

You didn't give us a concrete example, but I'm guessing you have a class like this:

```
In [387]: class MyClass(object):
     ...:     def add_account(self,*args):
     ...:         print(args)
     ...:         
In [388]: obj=MyClass()
In [389]: obj.add_account(*['one','two'])
('one', 'two')
```

To do the same thing, starting with a string, I can use `getattr` to fetch the method object:

```
In [390]: getattr(obj,'add_account')
Out[390]: <bound method MyClass.add_account of <__main__.MyClass object at 0x98ddaf2c>>
In [391]: getattr(obj,'add_account')('one')
('one',)
```

Now with your dictionary:

```
In [392]: dd={'add_account': ['example.com', 'example']}
In [393]: key='add_account'
In [394]: getattr(obj, key)(*dd[key])
('example.com', 'example')
```